# Get content of local-entry into property

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have a local-entry containing text. I want to use the text of the local-entry in my proxy sequence. But how can I do that?
I only have `get-property('name of property')`, but is there a `get-local-entry('name of local entry'`?

Here my Proxy in which I want to get the local-entry content:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MyProxy" transports="jms">
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">MyQueue</parameter>
    <target faultSequence="faultSequence">
        <inSequence>
            <!-- HERE I WANT TO ACCESS MY LOCAL-ENTRY -->
            <property name="myLocalEntry" expression="get-localEntry('asdf')"/> 
            <!-- then here i parse my data... -->
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

This is an example of the local-entry I need to access:

```
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="MyLocalEntry">
    My Local Entry Text
</localEntry>
```

**How can I get the local-entry text into my sequence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
get-property('MyLocalEntry')
```

to get the local entry text

Comment: Oh, same `get-property` as for inline properties! This really worked. Thanks

Comment: When  I used like above manner following error occur.  Cannot load JDBC driver class 'get-property('db_driver')'